# g++ complains undefined reference to '_register_callback'

Tags: c++, c, linker, cygwin

I tried compiling a dll under Cygwin with a '.a file' that was created via dlltool using foo.def file. In the .def file, I can see that `register_callback` exists:

```
EXPORTS
    ...
    register_callback @7569
    ...
```

The .a file was created using `dlltool --def foo.def --output-lib libfoo.a`.

However, when linking the main.o file, g++ complains that _register_callback is undefined.
`main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to '_register_callback'`

`g++ -shared -lfoo -o plugin.dll main.o`

`nm libfoo.a | grep 'register_callback'` shows:

```
00000000 b .bss$lazy_iregister_callback
00000000 r .rdata$lazy_iregister_callback
00000000 b __imp__register_callback
00000000 T _register_callback
00000000 b .bss$lazy_iunregister_callback
00000000 r .rdata$lazy_iunregister_callback
00000000 b __imp__unregister_callback
00000000 T _unregister_callback
```

It looks like with or without the -lfoo doesn't make a difference.

Any pointers towards solving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g++ -shared -lfoo -o plugin.dll main.o
```

should be

```
g++ -shared -o plugin.dll main.o -lfoo
```

i. e. move the linker flag that specifies a library **to the end of the command line invocation.** This is required for newer versions of GCC (rather the GNU toolchain) since `ld` now expects that the files be specified in the same order that the symbols depend on each other.

Comment: Will try it out tomorrow when I get back to the office!